# Calculate the MD5 hash from an online image

Tags: c#, image, url, buffer, md5

I need to calculate the MD5 hash of an online image

For a locally saved image, I tried this code and it works as expected:

```cs
public static string GetHashFromFile(string fileName, HashAlgorithm algorithm)
{
    HashAlgorithm MD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    using (var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fileName), 100000))
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(MD5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

How can I get the BufferedStream of an online file?

Comment: What about temporarily downloading the image, running your hash, and then deleting the image again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netcore-3.1) class to download the data from a given address. Use the downloaded bytes array to create a [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netcore-3.1) object to be the source stream of the [BufferedStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.bufferedstream?view=netcore-3.1) object.

You have two ways to download:

**1. The Synchronize Way**

```cs
static string GetHashFromUrl(string url)
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var bytes = wc.DownloadData(url);

        using (var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var bs = new BufferedStream(ms, 100_000))
            return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(bs)).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

... and a caller:

```cs
void TheCaller()
{
    try
    {
        var hash = GetHashFromUrl(url);
        //...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }            
}
```

**2. The Asynchronous Way**

```cs
static async Task<string> GetHashFromUrlAsync(string url)
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    using (var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] bytes = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
                
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var bs = new BufferedStream(ms, 100_000))
            return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(bs)).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

... and an `async` caller:

```cs
async void TheCaller()
{
    try
    {
        var hash = await Task.Run(() => GetHashFromUrlAsync(url));
        //...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }            
}
```

Both functions return the `FA544EB95534BA35AE9D6EA0B3889934` hash for [this](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-E5WKJfWSZPc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAWA/A1VKshOFuuU/photo.jpg?sz=328) photo which it's address is assigned to the `url` variable in the callers.